# karaf not finding installed bundle after restart

Tags: osgi, bundle, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

within karaf 3.0.3, I install the following bundle via maven by doing

```
bundle:install mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jcifs/1.3.17_1
```

This works just fine and all dependencies to other bundles are solved. But after a restart of my computer / karaf, this bundle does not seem to exist anymore since all dependent bundles fail to start. The bundle appears in the listing since
`bundle:list` gives me

```
450 | Active      |  80 | 1.3.17.1        | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jcifs
```

but if I try to access the bundle by restarting it e.g. the output is

```
bundle:restart 450
Bundle 450 is invalid
No bundles specified.
```

To fix it, I have to manually delete the bundle from the cache folder and install it again. It happened several times, so the issue can be reproduced. Since this is not reliable at all, I'm wondering what is going wrong here.

Comment: such questions are usually best addressed at the users mailinglist of the karaf project. Especially it's best to look for a similar issue there before.